# Copy all files from one folder to another Folder using PHP scripts?

Tags: php

Basically, my requirement is, I want to move all files from one folder to another folder using PHP scripts. Any one can help me. I am trying this, but I am getting error

```
 $mydir = dirname( __FILE__ )."/html/images/";
   if(!is_dir($mydir)){
       mkdir("html/images");
   } 
   // Move all images files
   $files = glob("images/*.");
   foreach($files as $file){
   $file_to_go = str_replace("images/","html/images/",$file);
       copy($file, $file_to_go);
   }
```

Comment: thanks i am getting the answer of my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// images folder creation using php
   $mydir = dirname( __FILE__ )."/html/images";
   if(!is_dir($mydir)){
   mkdir("html/images");
   }
   // Move all images files
   $files = glob("images/*.*");
   foreach($files as $file){
   $file_to_go = str_replace("images/","html/images/",$file);
         copy($file, $file_to_go);
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
<?php

   $src = 'pictures';
   $dst = 'dest';
   $files = glob("pictures/*.*");
   foreach($files as $file){
       $file_to_go = str_replace($src,$dst,$file);
       copy($file, $file_to_go);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(glob('old_directory/*.*') as $file) {
  copy('old_directory/'.$file, 'new_directory/'.$file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine:

```
// Get array of all source files
$files = scandir("source");
// Identify directories
$source = "source/";
$destination = "destination/";
// Cycle through all source files
foreach ($files as $file) {
  if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
  // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
  if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file))
  {
      $delete[] = $source.$file;
  }
}
// Delete all successfully-copied files
foreach ($delete as $file)
{
    unlink($file);
}
```

or with rename() and some error checking:

```
$srcDir = 'dir1';
$destDir = 'dir2';

if (file_exists($destDir)){
  if (is_dir($destDir)) {
    if (is_writable($destDir)) {
      if ($handle = opendir($srcDir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if (is_file($srcDir . '/' . $file)) {
            rename($srcDir . '/' . $file, $destDir . '/' . $file);
          }
        }
        closedir($handle);
      } else {
        echo "$srcDir could not be opened.\n";
      }
    } else {
      echo "$destDir is not writable!\n";
    }
  } else {
    echo "$destDir is not a directory!\n";
  }
} else {
  echo "$destDir does not exist\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array_map:

```
// images folder creation using php
function copyFile($file) {
   $file_to_go = str_replace("images/","html/images/",$file);
   copy($file, $file_to_go);
}
$mydir = dirname( __FILE__ )."/html/images";
if(!is_dir($mydir)){
  mkdir("html/images");
}

// Move all images files
$files = glob("images/*.*");
print_r(array_map("copyFile",$files));
```

Answer (score 1):

This One Works for me...........
Thanks to this man 
http://www.codingforums.com/php/146554-copy-one-folder-into-another-folder-using-php.html

```
 <?php
    copydir("admin","filescreate");
    echo "done";

    function copydir($source,$destination)
    {
    if(!is_dir($destination)){
    $oldumask = umask(0); 
    mkdir($destination, 01777); // so you get the sticky bit set 
    umask($oldumask);
    }
    $dir_handle = @opendir($source) or die("Unable to open");
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) 
    {
    if($file!="." && $file!=".." && !is_dir("$source/$file"))
    copy("$source/$file","$destination/$file");
    }
    closedir($dir_handle);
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this recursice function.

```
<?php 
    function copy_directory($source,$destination) { 
        $directory = opendir($source); 
        @mkdir($destination); 
        while(false !== ( $file = readdir($directory)) ) { 
            if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
                if ( is_dir($source . '/' . $file) ) { 
                    copy_directory($source . '/' . $file,$destination . '/' . $file); 
                } 
                else { 
                    copy($source . '/' . $file,$destination . '/' . $file); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        closedir($directory); 
    } 
?>
```

Referrence : http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I needed to copy from one domain to another, I solved it using a tiny adjustment to the "very easy answer" given by "coDe murDerer" above:
Here is exactly what worked in my case, you can as well adjust to suit yours:

```
foreach(glob('../folder/*.php') as $file) {
$adjust = substr($file,3);
copy($file, '/home/user/abcde.com/'.$adjust);
```

Notice the use of "substr()", without it, the destination becomes '/home/user/abcde.com/../folder/', which might be something you don't want. 
So, I used substr() to eliminate the first 3 characters(../) in order to get the desired destination which is '/home/user/abcde.com/folder/'. So, you can adjust the substr() function and also the glob() function until it fits your personal needs. Hope this helps.

Comment: To move files, use rename() in place of copy()